# Stoping the generation of duplicate of the output file

Tags: c#, excel, vba, winforms

I have an application where I generate Report at the end of all the materials, by Hitting generate Report button. The report is generated in Excel format. The problem is that whenever I create one report, I can create another report with the same name on the same location. It basically overrides the first report.

I want to give the user a box saying that you can generate a report with the same name or the name already exists and choose a different name.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not append the timestamp to filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before you save the file you should know what the Filename you are going to save it as. If so then just test if the File already exists. If it does then prompt the user for a new name and save it as the new name e.g.

```
string filename = @"C:\File.txt";

if(File.Exists(filename)){
    // Prompt for new one.
    // save the report to the new name instead.    
}else
{
   // save to filename
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about before saving a file, check if the file with this name already exists and if it does, offer to rename the file. Something like this:

```
if(File.Exists(proposedFileName)){
   showDialog("file exists, please choose other name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always do what DarkXphenomenon suggested, I append a mildate timestamp to the filename of the form:

```
<filename>_YYMMDD_HHMMSS.ext
```

While this is't rught for every situation, it has a lot of advantages:

1. Its simple, and it works
2. It saves me from having to write in all kinds of gyrations for going back and forth with the user over the name, overwriting, renaming, canceling, etc.  Usually deep in code that was never intended to have a user interface.
3. It makes automation much easier.
4. It makes testing easier.
5. It makes diagnosing user problems easier: there's no question over when a file was created or in what order they were created.

Answer (score -1):

Before creating the report you can iterate through the existing files and check whether the name already exists and give proper error message.

```
            string newFileName = "new file";
            string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("path");

            foreach (string file in fileNames)
            {
                if (file == newFileName)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: File.Exists() does just that for you.